# Can the new REST API now make WP into it's own push notification server?

Tags: rest-api

I'm not a coder by any stretch but if i'm not mistaken, if I wanted to use my WP website as a source of dynamic content inside a phone app then I'd need a 3rd party server to send the push notifications out to the app users, BUT now with the REST API I can now use my WP website as a push server for apps?

Answer (score 1):

Those technologies are totally independent of each other. The rest API can not be used as it is (in this context I mean the end points) for push notifications as there is a protocol for that and probably all kinds of restrictions browsers place. On the other end, nothing was preventing you from implementing those protocols before there was a rest API, and nothing prevents you from doing it now.

there are even plugins that claim to implement it for years by now https://wordpress.org/plugins/push-notifications-for-wp/ (no idea about the quality of it, was just the first result on google)

Comment: My understanding was those plugins can only push out with/to browsers and can only be pushed out with/to apps when you use a 3rd party (usually the plugin's server). I'm just trying to get my head around the big deal the API has going for it, in terms of making apps?

Comment: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-rest-api/
"Using the REST API, mobile developers will potentially be able to treat WordPress installs as just another server, with defined endpoints from the point of view of their apps. That fact alone opens up WordPress as a possible true backend for native mobile apps and paves the way for all manner of future integrations."

Comment: sorry, but I am not responsible for whatever iditic PR wpmudev does. The is no mgic in the rest API, all the things that it does could have been done earlier, maybe with somewhat more coding but definatly could have been done